# How the stack is overwritten via deferencing MOV operation [Assembler x86]?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, mov, ghidra

I am learning how to use Ghidra Tool and I have a question of how to interpret one function. This is the simplified version:

Take this scenario: the location `[RBP – 0x40]`, of the stack, has this value: `0xFFFF7710` (indeed this value is an address of another element in the stack... but for the question, this is irrelevant).

Now we store the address of that value in a register:

```
LEA RAX, [RBP – 0x40]
```

And finally, we execute these two instructions:

```
MOV EDX, 0xFFFF5520
MOV [RAX], DL
```

The final content in the stack `[RBP – 0x40]` is `0xFFFF7720`, `0x00000020` or `0xFFFFFF20` ?

Is overwritten all the content of the stack `[RBP – 0x40]` via the last `MOV` operation or only the last byte ?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the register names, you seem to be in 64-bit mode, in which case your `0xFFFF5520` is not an address but only half of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is `0xFFFF7720`.  Storing a byte to memory does not affect the other bytes of that word.  (You could test it...)